# Dimensional model or Relational model for data warehouse?

Tags: data-warehouse

I have a pretty trivial questions in data warehouse,

I know we use Dimensional data model to construct data marts and use Relational data model in staging area.

What data model technique we use to store data in central data warehouse? 
Can we use both? Which is most commonly used? 
We have RDBMS for relational database model, what is the database used for dimensional modelling?

Comment: Saying your question is "pretty trivial" makes me not want to look at the rest of your question.  Have you done any research; do you have specific concerns or problems?

Comment: Well there are "benchmarks" out there but sure i will believe NoSQL (mongodb) will outperform an RDBMS with one user but how will mongodb scale if more users connect? RDBMS are build to handle multiple users and this is proven for many years..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point of a data mart / warehouse is to facilitate analysis for non-DBAs. The relational model is wonderful for transactional databases to speed writes integrally, but is harder to understand for non-DBAs.

A data warehouse is a collection of data marts, or can act as a central data mart. If you are going to use dimensional modelling in your data marts (as you should), then you should use it in your warehouse as well.

You will find that most companies use regular RDBMSs (say, Oracle, SQL Server, Postgres) for their data warehouse, though you probably want one that supports materialized views and easy table partitioning. Some companies use columnar databases (say, MonetDB) or NoSQL databases (say, HBase) as well.